# .htaccess redirect .aspx to wordpress postname

Tags: .htaccess

I've migrated a custom ASP CMS to Wordpress. I need to 301 redirect:

`https://example.com/products/*.aspx`

to

`https://example.com/*`

How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only for this file, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)\.aspx$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Croises, it is for variable products.

Comment: I have updated the question to replace `product` with `*` - does that help?

Comment: The same now in my answer